# Python Mocking - How to mock regular expressions

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Does anyone know how to mock regular expressions? Or how can I make the following code work:

a.py

```
import re

def get_number_from_string():
    string = '3 monkies, 6 apes'
    string_split = string.split(',')

    fetch_number = re.match('[0-9]+', string_split[0])
    number = fetch_number.group(0)

    return number
```

test_a.py

```
import pytest
import a

def test_get_number_from_string():

    #with patch(somehow patch the re expression parts to return the int 10):

        number = a.get_number_from_string()

     assert number == 10
```

Comment: Just asking, why exactly do you need to mock regex? It's built into python.

Comment: Just wondering if its possible to directly manipulate regex as a mock. I know I can get re.match to work (patched as "a.re.match") but the group method is where I'm struggling because its being invoked from a string NOT the re lib or a class or something.

Comment: Actually, the `group` method is a member of the `re.MatchObject` class, which is what `re.match` returns. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

Comment: That helps out somewhat.